# How to paging in datatable using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to read file between two date and add the value to a datatable. Then want to show datatable value in a grid with paging. But the problem is that these file contains huge amount of data (more than 1M) so if I use gridview default paging my application hang. so I want to paging in datatable.so how can I do that? Any idea of sample code please.

```
public DataTable CreateDataSource(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    int i = 0;
    string visitorCountry = "";
    try
    {
        dt = dtVisitLog();
        for (DateTime x = fromDate; x <= toDate; x = x.AddDays(1))
        {
            string startDate = x.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2) + x.Month.ToString("d2") + x.Day.ToString("d2");
            string FILE_NAME = pathName + "\\u_ex" + startDate + ".log";
            if (File.Exists(FILE_NAME))
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILE_NAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
                                               FileShare.ReadWrite);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
                string strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Dispose();
                fs.Dispose();
                sr = null;
                fs = null;
                string[] arLogLines = strResult.Split(Convert.ToChar("\n"));

                for (i = arLogLines.Length-2; i > 3; i--)
                {
                   string[] attribute = arLogLines[i].Split(Convert.ToChar(" "));                
                   dt.Rows.Add(attribute[0], attribute[1], attribute[8], attribute[4], attribute[7], visitorCountry);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, Datatable limit is 16,777,216 rows. so when you load huge data into datatable it impact on performance of application and server memory. So it better 1st store this huge data into Database like SQL server or other database. Then display data using row number function (if you use MS SQL 2005 or 2008). If you use SQL Server 2012 then you can use fetch . If you you use MySQL server then you can use limit for displaying limited data at a time. What i try to explain to you that you need server side pagination not client side pagination in this situation. Thanks.